# HeaderCell is only being added once to table view

Tags: ios, swift

To display each user input I created a table view which displays an array of structs. It works fine, but I'm currently trying to add a `headerCell` to each entry displaying the date of the input.

Therefore I created another cell called `DateCell` displaying the date. Additionally I added: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int)` to the TableViewController.

My approach is working, but only partially - the `DateCell` is being displayed but only once with all `timelineCells` containing the entries underneath. Every time a entry and therefore a `timelineCell` is being added, the date inside of the `DateCell` is solely being updated, but I want every `timelineCell` to have its own `DateCell` with its own date.

**TableViewController**

```
class TimelineViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolbar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var timlineView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonBack: UIBarButtonItem!

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var isAsc = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sortArray()
        self.setToolbarInvisible(toolbar: toolbar)
        timlineView.delegate = self
        timlineView.dataSource = self
        setShadow()
    }

    ...

    func sortArray() {
        addDataArray.sort(by: { $1.date < $0.date })
    }

}

extension TimelineViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return addDataArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

        cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
        cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
        cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let rowData = addDataArray[section]
        let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell") as! DateCell

        headerCell.setDate(date: rowData.date)

        return headerCell
    }

}
```

**HeaderCell**

```
class DateCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!

    func setDate(date: Date) {
        let date = date
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"

        let currentDate = formatter.string(from: date)
        dateLabel.text = currentDate
    }

}
```

Comment: you cannot have multiple header views for a section. Each section has only one header and one footer view. You might have to use cellForRow, and modify it to show different cells.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I tried that as well, how can I return two cells inside of cellForRow?

Comment: instead, implement numberOfSections and return addDataArray.count, and change numberOfRows to return 1

Comment: @SeanLintern doing so indeed adds a header on each timlineCell - but somehow every entry is being overwritten by the last input

Comment: let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.row] needs to be indexPath.section

Comment: @SeanLintern Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sean mentioned in his comment, you can create a section for every entry of addDataArray.

You need to return sections count and change numberOfRows to 1 in each section. Also you need to change the way you retrieve data for you timeline cells, using section instead of row.

So you need to change your UITableViewDelegate methods like this:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 1
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return addDataArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.section]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

    cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
    cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
    cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

    return cell
}
```

Alternatively you can double your cells count and return both header and items as cells

Then you need to make these changes:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return addDataArray.count * 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
       let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.row / 2 ]

       let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateCell") as! DateCell

        headerCell.setDate(date: rowData.date)

        return headerCell
   } else {
        let rowData = addDataArray[indexPath.row / 2]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TimelineCell") as! TimelineCell

        cell.setDrivenKm(drivenKm: rowData.driven)
        cell.setConsumedL(consumedL: rowData.consumedL)
        cell.setPricePerLiter(pricePerLiter: rowData.pricePerLiter)

        return cell
    }
}
```

I've created a playground to show an example. Check it out [here](https://github.com/shles/DoubleCells).

Comment: Thanks! Using the first approach indeed displayed each timlineView with its own header, but every cell displayed the data from the array's last index. The second approach showed following error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`.

Comment: @Tim I've updated my answer recently. Have you tried the last version?

Comment: @Tim I've added a link to the example of my solution implemented in the Playground

Comment: Works fine, but it kind of changes the height of my header cell I've set in storyboard. It adapts the same height for both cells.

Comment: @Tim If you using autolayout for bot cells, in viewDidLoad set         ```tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension``` and  ```tableView.estimatedRowHeight = *your basic height*```